# Can I use mapreduce with a pair of Keys and a pair of values?

Tags: hadoop

My question is theoretical,

I'm trying to make a design for a mapreduce example in Big data processing.

The case which I have requires a pair of keys to be mapped to a pair of values.

for example if we have below text:
"Bachelors in Engineering has experience of 5 years"
I am trying to count the words Engineering & Experience in a way where I would have a value for each word separately.

So my key would be (Engineering,Experience) and my value would be (1,1) as per the above given text example.

Note that there is a relationship between both key values in my homework, therefore I want them both in one set of a key-value to determine if both keys are mentioned in one text file, or only one key is mentioned, or none is mentioned.

Please let me know if above case is possible to do in map-reduce of big data or not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the Answer, but I figured I could use "Engineering Experience" as a string for the key.

Answer (score 1):

Having a string key of `"(Engineering,Experience)"` is no different than just having a String of one of those words.

If you want to have some more custom type, then you will want to subclass the `Writable` and maybe the `WritableComparable` interfaces.

Simlarly, for the value, you could put the entire tuple as `Text` and parse it later, or you can create your own Writable subclass that can store two integers.